# Using Angular Scenario to test 'any web page'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo, karma-runner

I am wondering if it's possible to test any web page with the angular scenario tester (and karma).

Or is it designed to only work with angular source code?

In other words, is it generic an not 'really' tied to angular?

I am writing an angularJs app with yeoman and I like the way e2e testing is done thanks to ngResource.

I have another app, not written in angular, but in dojo and I would like to test it the same way.

Do you think it is possible and if yes what would be your advice on how to do it?

Thank you!

Note : actually the tested web page has some angular code in it or not, so the question makes sense. Tools such as casperJs, or selenium are independent from what js technology is in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it is easily feasible. You just need

1/ to install karma

> npm install -g karma

2/ Install dependencies for ng-scenario and karma-ng-scenario

> ```
> npm install ng-scenario
>
> npm install karma-ng-scenario --save-dev
> ```

3/ Create / Modify the karma e2e configuration if a proxy is needed. It's the case
    generally as dojo runs on a different server than karma. So you
    specify a specific port for karma and you proxy to your server. Here
    is an example of my configuration:

> module.exports = function(config) {   config.set({
>       // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
>       basePath: '',
>
> ```
> // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
> frameworks: ['ng-scenario'],
>
> // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
> files: [
>    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js',
>   'test/e2e/**/*.js'
> ],
>
> // list of files / patterns to exclude
> exclude: [],
>
> // web server port
> port: 8033,
>
> runnerPort : 9100,
>
> // level of logging
> // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
> logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
>
>
> // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
> autoWatch: false,
>
>
> // Start these browsers, currently available:
> // - Chrome
> // - ChromeCanary
> // - Firefox
> // - Opera
> // - Safari (only Mac)
> // - PhantomJS
> // - IE (only Windows)
> browsers: ['Chrome'],
>
>
> // Continuous Integration mode
> // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
> singleRun: false,
>
> // Uncomment the following lines if you are using grunt's server to run the tests
> proxies: {
>    '/': 'http://localhost:8080/'
> }, //    URL root prevent conflicts with the site root
> urlRoot: '_karma_'   }); };
> ```

1. You run karma with the end to end configuration

> ```
> karma start karma-e2e.conf.js
> ```

Magic, the following code works - happy testing :)

```
describe ( 'Publications', function ()
{
   beforeEach (
      function ()
      {
         console.log ( "before each" );
         browser ().navigateTo ( "yourPageToTestUrl" );
      }
   );

   it ( 'should filter results', function ()
   {
      expect ( repeater ( '.Publication' ).count () ).toEqual ( 4 );
   } );

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that some test code will work (such as counting elements), some other will not (such as setting an input not reared by Angular).

Here is a tool that tries make ngScenarios work with any JS tool : http://davidb583.github.io/BlackboxJS